# Difference in how docker labels are applied in multi-stage builds across platform / version

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The following dockerfile produces different results on the CI and my local machine

```
FROM python:3.7-slim as image1
LABEL io.astronomer.docker=true

FROM image1 as image2
LABEL io.astronomer.docker.image2=true

FROM image1 as image3
LABEL io.astronomer.docker.image3=true
```

**CI**:

Label: `"io.astronomer.docker.image2": "true"` is present even though it is not in final image

```
circleci@15f73c18db20:~/aa$ docker inspect kaxil/test1 | jq -r '.[0].Config.Labels'
{
  "io.astronomer.docker": "true",
  "io.astronomer.docker.image2": "true",
  "io.astronomer.docker.image3": "true"
}
```

Version:

```
circleci@15f73c18db20:~$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.12
 API version:       1.32
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        48a66213fe
 Built:             Mon Jun 22 15:42:53 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          17.09.0-ce
  API version:      1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.8.3
  Git commit:       afdb6d4
  Built:            Tue Sep 26 22:40:56 2017
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

**Local**:

Labels:

```
❯ docker inspect kaxil/test1 | jq -r '.[0].Config.Labels'
{
  "io.astronomer.docker": "true",
  "io.astronomer.docker.image3": "true"
}
```

Version:

```
❯ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.2
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 16:58:31 2020
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.13
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       4484c46d9d
  Built:            Wed Sep 16 17:07:04 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.3.7
  GitCommit:        8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Can someone explain why the CI environment shows the label `io.astronomer.docker.image2` even though it is not used in the final image?

Both the images are just built using the following command:

```
❯ docker build -t kaxil/test1 . --file Dockerfile
```

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm facing a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68905984/297331

Comment: Unfortunately not :( @NieldeWet