# Docker LABEL to access build image in multi-stage build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

During my CI build I extract build artifacts from the build image in a multi-stage Docker build (test reports) by adding a `LABEL` build step and then creating a container with the labeled image to extract the artifact. This seems to be broken in Docker Desktop for Mac, or I misunderstand how this is supposed to work?

Here is a minimal build to reproduce the issue:

```
# Dockerfile.one

FROM alpine AS one

WORKDIR /test
RUN touch here
LABEL build=here
```

```
# Dockerfile.two

FROM alpine AS one

WORKDIR /test
RUN touch here
LABEL build=here

FROM alpine AS two
COPY --from=one /test/* /test/
RUN touch again
```

```
# test.sh
#! /bin/bash -u

# Clean up
trap 'rm -r test & docker rmi $image' EXIT

docker build -f $1 .
docker images --filter 'label=build=here'

image=$(docker images --filter 'label=build=here' -q | head -n 1)
id=$(docker create $image) && docker cp $id:/test/ . && docker rm $id
ls -l test
```

Running `./test.sh Dockerfile.one` (only one stage) produces the expected output of the file `here` being present in the working directory.

However, running `./test.sh Dockerfile.two` (multi-stage) fails, apparently because no images match `--filter label=build=here`.

What is wrong here?

---

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: 1.0.17
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.4
 Git commit:        f0df350
 Built:             Wed Jun  2 11:56:22 2021
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.7
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       b0f5bc3
  Built:            Wed Jun  2 11:54:58 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

Comment: In dockerfile.two stage 2, you base it on `alpine`. That means that all the steps in stage one (including your LABEL statement) will get thrown out once the image is built. If you place the LABEL statement after `FROM alpine AS two` I'm pretty sure the label will end up in the image.

Comment: @HansKilian that may be true, but it doesn't help me to access files from the first image that are not in the second one. Like not having test reports in the run image.

Comment: One of the main points of doing a multistage build is to *not* have all the clutter from your build included in the final image. If you want to keep it, then do a single stage build or copy the things your want to keep into the final stage.

Comment: Thanks @HansKilian. Maybe I should clarify that I don't want the artifact in the final image, but I want to access it in the build environment, for example adding it to the CI build result. Therefore I'm trying to copy the artifact out of the intermediary image without affecting the final.

Comment: @NieldeWet I'm at the same point - did you find a solution?

Comment: @Eike unfortunately not.